# Call knockout viewmodel function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jscrollpane

How to call a viewmodel function in a jQuery function? I just want to call a function of viewmodel function from a Javascript function.

```
function ContactsViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  // Editable data
  self.Contacts = ko.observableArray(JSON.parse(data));
  self.limit = ko.observable(20);
  self.changeNumber = function(item){
    self.limit(self.limit()+20);
    self.Contacts.push(item);
  }
  self.myPostProcessingLogic = function(elements) {
    if ($('#KnockOutContacts').children().length === ko.toJS(self.Contacts).length) {
      // Only now execute handler
      jq();
    }
  }
}
```

How to call `changeNumber` from the `jscroll` pane function?

```
$('.jspScrollable').bind(
  'jsp-arrow-change',
  function(event, isAtTop, isAtBottom, isAtLeft, isAtRight) {
    // Now look at the is* parameters and do what you
    // need to do. All four of the is* parameters are booleans.
    if(isAtBottom) {
      ContactsViewModel.changeNumber();
    }
  }
);
```

the data is coming from server

```
function returnData(url,data,type){
    $.post(url, data, function(returnedData) {

    if(type == "contacts")
    {   
    ko.applyBindings(new ContactsViewModel(returnedData),$("#KnockOutContacts")[0]);    
    }
    else if(type == "logs")
    {
    ko.applyBindings(new LogsViewModel(returnedData),$("#KnockOutLogs")[0]);    
    }
    else if(type == "sms")
    {
        ko.applyBindings(new SmsViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutSms"),$("#KnockOutSms")[0]);   
    ko.applyBindings(new SmsViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutSmsData"),$("#KnockOutSmsData")[0]);   


    }
});
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an object of the ContactsViewModel created? `var myVM = new ContactsViewModel(somedata);` ? Then you can do a `myVM.ChangeNumber(someItem);`

Comment: no because i was calling it in this function


function returnData(url,data,type){
 $.post(url, data, function(returnedData) {
 
 if(type == "contacts")
 { 
 ko.applyBindings(new ContactsViewModel(returnedData),$("#KnockOutContacts")[0]); 
 }
 else if(type == "logs")
 {
 ko.applyBindings(new LogsViewModel(returnedData),$("#KnockOutLogs")[0]); 
 }
 else if(type == "sms")
 {
  ko.applyBindings(new SmsViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutSms"),$("#KnockOutSms")[0]); 
 ko.applyBindings(new SmsViewModel(returnedData,"#KnockOutSmsData"),$("#KnockOutSmsData")[0]); 

 
 }
});
}

Comment: Can you add this code to your question and format it ?

Comment: You can try to obtain your viewmodel instance by this `var myVM = ko.contextFor($("#KnockOutContacts")[0]); myVM.ChangeNumber(somenewItem)`. Also check this KO documentation link on how to use this better, http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Anders about using custom bindings. But if you really want to, try returning 'self' from your ContactsViewModel (see example below)

```
function ContactsViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  // Editable data
  self.Contacts = ko.observableArray(JSON.parse(data));
  self.limit = ko.observable(20);
  self.changeNumber = function(item){
    self.limit(self.limit()+20);
    self.Contacts.push(item);
  }
  self.myPostProcessingLogic = function(elements) {
    if ($('#KnockOutContacts').children().length === ko.toJS(self.Contacts).length) {
      // Only now execute handler
      jq();
    }
  }

  //return self
  return self;

}

//Variable you'll use to reference in jQuery
var myVm = ContactsViewModel(yourdata);
ko.applyBindings(myVm);

myVm.changeNumber(yourItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom binding that hooks up the jQuery stuff. You should never have any DOM related code in your viewmodels its a antipattern.

Something like (Not working code)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.scrollable = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var onScroll = valueAccessor();
      $(element).bind(
        'jsp-arrow-change',
        function(event, isAtTop, isAtBottom, isAtLeft, isAtRight) {
        // Now look at the is* parameters and do what you
        // need to do. All four of the is* parameters are booleans.
        if(isAtBottom) {
           onScroll();
        }
      });
   }
};
```

THen used from your view like

```
<div data-bind="scrollable: changeNumber"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can do something like this:

---

**ViewModel**

```
var searchViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.search = function (param) {
        //do something
    };
}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { Search() }" class="" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
```

---

**Jquery**

```
function Search() {
    // paramvalue = 1; 
    viewModel.search(paramvalue);                  
}
```